# Encrypt appsettings and other configurations in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I wondering how to encrypt information in appsettings.json in asp.net core 2.0. I am looking for a way to encrypt connectionstring and other credentials or sensitive informations that can be store in appsettings.json in a production environment. [Users secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=windows) is only recommand for development purpose so they don't fit that requirements. Also i can't use Azure Key vault.

Answer (score 0):

While not encrypted, you can use environment variables to store your sensitive information instead of including it within your appsettings.json file. This allows you to use user secrets in development and environment variables in production

If you're using Azure it will be under Application Settings.

Comment: Using env variables is not a solution prod prod environment. Especially when it comes to the maintenance.